# Understanding "runtime mcycles" and "cpu_ms" accounting on AppEngine's Go runtime

Tags: google-app-engine, go

I have a Go/AppEngine app that I'm trying to fine-tune to optimize concurrent requests, which is currently cpu-bound. In the process of doing so, I'm seeing what look like anomalous values for `cpu_ms` in the logs, and `average runtime mcycles` in the dashboard.

I have a few different endpoints whose cpu use seems completely at odds with reality, but one in particular stands out. It's a simple handler that reads roughly as follows:

```
    func ThangHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        ctx := appengine.NewContext(r)

        var orgId string
        cookie, err := r.Cookie(orgCookieKey)
        if err != nil || cookie.Value == "" {
            // Check URL params as a fallback.
            r.ParseForm()
            orgId = r.Form.Get("orgId")
            if orgId == "" {
                util.HttpError(ctx, w, http.StatusForbidden)
                return
            }
        } else {
            orgId = cookie.Value
        }

        w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8")
        fmt.Fprintf(w, simpleTemplate, orgId, r.Host, "true", host)
    }
```

The details of this code don't matter so much as the fact that it doesn't do much more than read a cookie/param and run a Printf on a very simple template string (maybe 100 characters or so).

As I write this, the AppEngine dashboard is reporting this endpoint as consuming `83 runtime mcycles` average over the last hour, which seems surprisingly high. When I look at the top 20 log entries associated with these requests, I see an even stranger picture. Most of them are either `ms=13 cpu_ms=0` or `ms=13 cpu_ms=21` (I assume there's some quantization going on there). But about 10% are *really* odd, such as `ms=148 cpu_ms=238`!

So my actual question is this:

- How can an endpoint this simple possibly consume 83 average mcycles, and have such high variance?

  - Should I suspect GC pauses?
- How is it *ever* possible that `cpu_ms > ms` in the logs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the benefit of anyone that comes across this question in the future, here is the answer given by dsymonds on the google-appengine-go mailing list:

> The cpu_ms and related accounting measures are legacy holdovers from 
>   the old billing structure, which was based at least partly on CPU 
>   consumption. Nowadays it is meaningless from that perspective, and I 
>   wouldn't be surprised if those numbers are somewhat nonsensical.
>
> There's nothing in the Go runtime done to attribute CPU time to 
>   separate requests, nor is it really tractable to do so in a concurrent
>   runtime. The attributing is statistical in nature, which may account 
>   for the weirdness you are seeing.